# How to say "items remaining from last meeting"?

Tags: words, translation

I am setting up a meeting agenda and of the items is "covering the items left over from last meeting".

I though something like "前回のミーティングの残件” Would have worked but it turns out that 残件 isn't a word and I have having trouble finding alternatives.

Any ideas?

Comment: `残件` does exist.

Comment: Would 未処理の～ work?

Comment: How about using [継続]{けいぞく}([案件]{あんけん})? ([持越]{もちこ}し案件 might sound a bit too colloquial for an agenda...) I think 残件 would be alright, too.

Comment: What about `未解決の（用）件`?

Comment: According to weblio it does exist.
(http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AE%8B%E4%BB%B6) Also, I fail at making inline links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Japanese here. 残件 is a totally appropriate word that would be correctly understood in a business setting. But boy, you are right, it's not in the dictionary!

If you insist on finding a word that's in the dictionary, I'd suggest 未決案件 or 未決事項. 未決 and 既決 are often used in a business set up (sometimes you see a box labeled), and 案件/事項 both refer vaguely to a thing, an issue, or a matter, making it usable in a broad context. Plus they are formal enough.

Comment: this is old but 懸案 also exists